# How to create an orbit of three elements around a logo

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, css-transitions, orbit

I'm a newbie and I'm on my first project:

I have three elements (images) and a logo.

When I click on an image this one and the other two ones should move in an orbit of 360° around the logo (with a low z-index when they go on the back of the logo so they can disappear and then reappear).

Is this possible with jquery and css3?

Comment: Hiya there! I can flick you a jsfiddle with orbit movements in jquery and css (for solar system sample) and you can read the code and put your logo instead of sun; DOes that sounds good to you? if that answer sounds acceptable solution then please let me know, Have a nice one, cheerios!

Comment: Yes, I would really appreciate that if it's not time-sucker for you!

Comment: Cooleos Wait bruv, gimme 2 mins! cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiya **2 demos** starts with simple:

**1)** (using divs) http://jsfiddle.net/ErN8X/2/show & code: http://jsfiddle.net/ErN8X/2/

**2)** http://jsfiddle.net/qXP7H/show/ and code: http://jsfiddle.net/qXP7H/

Please see here as well: [jQuery plugin to make an element orbit another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454667/jquery-plugin-to-make-an-element-orbit-another)

For the second demo you can copy paste the code from jsfiddle. rest this should help, have a nice one, and don't forget to accept answer if this helps.! :)

**Jquery for simple demo**

```
var angle = 0;     // starting position (degrees)
var distance = 30; // distance of b from a
var speed = 60;    // revolution speed in degrees per second
var rate  = 10;    // refresh rate in ms

function f() {

    var o = $('#a').offset();

    var t = o.top + (distance * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l = o.left+ (distance * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180.0));

    $('#b').css({
        top: t,
        left: l
    });
    $('#c').css({
        top: t + 20,
        left: l + 30
    });
    $('#d').css({
        top: t +40,
        left: l +40
    });
    angle += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;
}

setInterval(f, rate);
​
```

Comment: Hiya @Mattia just copy paste the code i.e. html to html place Jquery and css from jsfiddle to your page and that should do the trick thats why I flicked jsfiddle. I am bit uncomfortable using your external link from laptop which aint mine, :) anyhoo hope if above example helped you the accept it, cheerios :)

Comment: Sorry Tats but the link I've posted it's an image, a preview of what I would like to do. I don't know how to post it on jsfiddle, it doesn't appear!

The examples you've posted have different orbits, mine has three images (that we'll call planet) on the same orbit, is it possible to adapt your example with the planets on the new position? Sorry for my ignorance and bad english, hope I'm not asking the moon!! (while we’re on the subject of solar system :D)

Comment: Hiya @Mattia http://jsfiddle.net/ErN8X/10/ or this with planets on same orbit scroll to the bottom of the script and play around with the orbit function where the "new position for the orbiting" happens; hope this helps, :) cheers

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to play with the code you posted and adapt it to my needs!

Comment: Cool @Mattia sounds like a plan. No worries at all! I will see if I can take a look before I sleep, take care!

Comment: @Mattia here you go please play around with css as well I have make it a way that all 3 planet - mercury venus and earth now revolves one after another in same orbit http://jsfiddle.net/aLVnR/9/show/  & code: http://jsfiddle.net/aLVnR/9/ ;rest you know what are you doing! :) good luck! cheerios