# Rotate multiple images in a circle using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-animate

I need to rotate multiple images in the same orbit circle using jquery.I changed and delayed the time intervals for both the images. The problem is both the images are overlapping after few seconds.  my code is

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var p = 0;

            function moveit() {
            p += 0.02;

            var r = 135;
            var xcenter = 500;
            var ycenter = 200;
            var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(p)));
            var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(p)));
            $('#friends').animate({
                    top: newTop,
                    left: newLeft,
                }, 10, function() {
                    moveit();
            $('#friends2').animate({
                top: newTop,
                left: newLeft,
            },15, function() {
                moveit();
            });
             }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                moveit();    
            });
            </script>
```

my css and html source codes are

```
   #friends { position: absolute;     }         
     #friends2 { position: absolute;    }     

 <img src="Images/info.gif" id="friends"/>
<img src="Images/circle.jpg" id="circles" />
<img src="Images/help.gif" id="friends2" />
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/embedded/result/ but this is for single image..
Any suggestion ??

edit::
    my image
[image: rotation of images]

or

sample link http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38228.html

Comment: Hiya, You might get good idea from one of my old replies here man: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294720/how-to-create-an-orbit-of-three-elements-around-a-logo please take a look; cheerios! **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5fvc5/ let me know if this helps, I will set it as answer!

Comment: thanks Tats_innit.but i need to rotate three images in d same orbit without overlapping.??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5fvc5/3/ let me know if you want me to set this as answer, cheers

Comment: When you say rotate, you mean cycle through the images, not spin the around an axis, yes?

Comment: thanks again .Tats_innit.. see my image and i want the images to rotate in d orbit..

Comment: I got your code to work correctly, (I think.)  I misread your desire at first.  I don't know if you want them to rotate at different speeds but that's what I accomplished.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qXP7H/15/ perhaps, you can play around with css, have a good one, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Check this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/FyMCc/4/)

It has two items which is **rotating on same orbit at same speed**. It will never overlap.

**EDIT:**

And [**here is the example**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/FyMCc/13/) for 4 items to be rotated at same speed and same orbit but equally separated.

To add more items, just tweak the code by adding different angle to it.

**UPDATE:**

[***And here is the simple image version***](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/Pvtzv/1/)

Hope this will help. Cheers !!!

Comment: thanks libin .. can i stop the rotation when it hovers on the image ??

Comment: As per the code, it will never stop. If you are seeing it stops the rotation, then it probably when jQuery crashes or some cache error.

Comment: can you indicate which determines the speed of the rotation ?? . p value or the value 10 in moveit() function ??

Comment: Its better to change the `p` value.

Comment: what is the difference between these two values ?

Comment: `p` is the angle to change on moveit() function at each step. I don't know the correct difference btwn them.

Comment: This is really great -- could you show how to do it for 5 images?

Comment: You can do it yourself. Check the script. Divide the 360 degree circle into 5. So the angle is 72 degree. Rewrite the script according to that angle. Simple math. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, though it looks like you had a syntax error; your first moveit call was not properly ended.

This one has same orbit, different speeds
http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/FyMCc/

**EDIT**

Your error was putting the command to rotate both of items in the same function.  They both grabbed the same top and left and were always mutually bound, not to mention they both called moveit() so for every time moveit was called, it would be called twice more internally.

I've fixed your recursion so it only happens once, and made moveit accept the target element as well as a different starting position (shift).

This one has same orbit, same speed, different locations
http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/QAT7C/11/

Comment: Its still overlapping.. Watch it for 20secs

Comment: So you want them on different locations, on the same orbit, at different speeds?

Comment: I made an edit that does the same orbit at the same speed but different locations.