# central image with smaller images rotating around the outside

Tags: html, css

I need to have a central large image with smaller images rotating around the outside of it. Can it be done with css and html?

Also, what's the code to do this static?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get positive reactions here, please show what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is more .. give me a code. We are a Q&A that helps with developping or repairs something that you missed in code. We dont actually hand out code like this. If that would be the case, we would be charging money ;-)

Comment: You can achieve this using jQuery. [Check this answer I had written for a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10564980/1083494)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't with HTML/CSS. With javascript you can do pretty easily by some trigonometric calculations

Comment: Wrong, this is possible with CSS3 animations

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you could use SVG (vector file format). But I'm not sure whether the animation support can accomplish this. Also keep in mind that the browser support might be a problem.

Comment: @Andy: Ok, pardon I didn't know about. Thank you :)